# How can I set parameter's value for player clone in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a transfer code, if player clone touched the door, player will transfer to another room. But it doesn't work. I think 'currentMapName' is only set in player object, not clone object. So I want to know how can I set parameter of clone object. Thanks for anything your helps.

---

the error code

[image]

---

transfom source code

```cs
public string  transferMapName; // map name for transform

private PlayerScript thePlayer;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    thePlayer = FindObjectOfType<PlayerScript>(); // player objects.
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Player(Clone)")
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit door");
        thePlayer.currentMapName = transferMapName;
        Debug.Log(thePlayer.currentMapName);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(transferMapName);
    }
}
```

---

and clone parameter that I want set value

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect, that your `thePlayer` object is null, as the NullReference appears after "Hit door" log. I guess you spawn/clone the player after `Start()` has run. So, easy ways to fix that:

**Option A:**

```cs
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Player(Clone)")
    {
        if(thePlayer == null)
        {
            thePlayer  = FindObjectOfType<PlayerScript>(); // careful if you have more than one Player!
            if(thePlayer == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("NO Player Found!");
                return;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("Hit door");
        thePlayer.currentMapName = transferMapName;
        Debug.Log(thePlayer.currentMapName);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(transferMapName);
    }
}
```

**Option B (preferred):**

```cs
if (collision.gameObject.name == "Player(Clone)")
{
    Debug.Log("Hit door");
    if (collision.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out PlayerScript player))
    {
        Debug.Log("Player script found!");

        player.currentMapName = transferMapName;
        Debug.Log(player.currentMapName);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(transferMapName);
    }        
}
```

**Option C**: Spawn your Player in `Awake()` so it can be found in `Start()`

**Option D**: Assign the Player Reference to the OnTriggerEnter Object, where you make `thePlayer` public and drag-drop the player, if it's already available in the scene during editmode.

Comment: The `TryGetComponent` method is fine and no longer requires the `collision.gameObject.name == "player (clone)"` condition, as all players have it.

Comment: Then you can use getComponent directly of course.

Comment: Thankyou!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I choose optionB, and it worked very well !!!!!!! you save my project. I'm really apprieciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change the condition to having a player script.

```cs
var playerScript = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerScript>();

if (playerScript)
{
    playerScript.currentMapName = transferMapName; // for e.g
}
```

Comment: I think this solution first time but it still doesn't work